# How update part of record, SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server

Is there a way to update a part of a record in SQL Server 2008

I have a table looking like:

```
Name             Country Name(1)
Tulipa Apeldoorn FRA     Tulipes Apeldoorn
Tulipa Abba      FRA     Tulipes Abba
Tulipa Rai       FRA     Tulipa Rai
Tulipa Ozz       FRA     Tulipa Ozz
```

Now I want all records to begin with `Tulipes`...

What's the fastest way?

Answer (score 2):

You can filter with the where-clause

```
UPDATE myTable
SET *name = REPLACE(*name, 'Tulipa', 'Tulipes')
WHERE *name like 'Tulipa%'
```

*name = your columnname

Comment: I want Tulipa replaced with Tulipes. And I cant do it by Record because there to many... I know how to make a filter, but dont know the way to updat a kolom and replace all records in Name(1) how start with Tulipa to start with Tulipes..

Comment: ah ok.. You can update your records with replace... i changed my answer

Answer (score 2):

```
select * from <myTable> where [name(1)] like 'Tulipes%'


Name             Country Name(1)
Tulipa Apeldoorn FRA     Tulipes Apeldoorn
Tulipa Abba      FRA     Tulipes Abba


update <myTable> set [name(1)]='your text'  where [name(1)] like 'Tulipes%'
```